# Repeating the same pattern on a regex in java?

Tags: java, regex

I have a string which may have one of two formats:

- `(someName,true);` (where someName can be any combination of letters and numbers, and after the comma we have either `true` or `false`)
- `(someName,true), (anything,false), (pepe12,true);` and in this case, we can have as many parenthesis groups as can be, but they are separated with a comma plus white space.

Given the following test set:

```
(hola,false);
comosoy12,true);
caminare)
true,comoestas
```

I used the following regex `^\(.*,(true|false)[)][;$]` and got my expected result of `true, false, false, false` ([quick check here](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html)). But I cannot seem to come up with the regex for the following cases:

```
(someName,true), (anything,false), (pepe12,true);
(hola,false);
comosoy12,true);
(batman,true), (kittycat,false);
(batman,true); (kittycat,false);
```

Which should return `true, true, false, true, false`.

Comment: `s.matches("^\\(\\w+,(?:true|false)\\)(?:, \\(\\w+,(?:true|false)\\))*;")` or `s.matches("^\\(\\w+,(?:true|false)\\)(?:,\\s+\\(\\w+,(?:true|false)\\))*;")`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use

```
^\(\w+,(?:true|false)\)(?:,\s*\(\w+,(?:true|false)\))*;$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OCwpFA/2/). Note `.*` in your pattern can match any 0+ chars other than line break chars while you want to match letters and digits, thus I suggest `\w` (note it also matches `_`) or, you may use `\p{Alnum}` or `[A-Za-z0-9]`.

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\(\w+,(?:true|false)\)` - `block`: `(`, 1+ word chars (or alhphanumeric if you use `[a-zA-Z0-9]` or `\p{Alnum}`), `,`, `true` or `false`
- `(?:,\s*\(\w+,(?:true|false)\))*` - 0 or more sequences of

  - `,` - comma
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `\(\w+,(?:true|false)\)` - `block` pattern
- `;` - a `;` char
- `$` - end of string

In Java, you may build the regex dynamically and since you want a full string match with `matches`, you may discard the initial `^` and final `$` anchors:

```
String block = "\\(\\w+,(?:true|false)\\)";
String regex = block + "(?:,\\s+" + block + ")*;";
bool result = s.matches(regex);
```

See Java demo online:

```
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("(someName,true), (anything,false), (pepe12,true);","(hola,false);","comosoy12,true);", "(batman,true), (kittycat,false);", "(batman,true); (kittycat,false);");
String block = "\\(\\w+,(?:true|false)\\)";
String regex = block + "(?:,\\s+" + block + ")*;";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
for (String str : strs)
    System.out.println(str + " => " + p.matcher(str).matches());
```

Output:

```
(someName,true), (anything,false), (pepe12,true); => true
(hola,false); => true
comosoy12,true); => false
(batman,true), (kittycat,false); => true
(batman,true); (kittycat,false); => false
```

Comment: This one is great! What if I want to allow _ (underscore) and - (dash) on the name where I put the .*?

Comment: @Mel `\w` matches an underscore. To allow `-`, use `[\w-]+` instead of `\w+`.